# Error 503 on Wordpress site: Backend Fetch Failed

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have recently updated my Wordpress website with a new theme, and have enabled gzip compression by adding the code to my htaccess file as specified by GTMetrix: https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html

However, I will occasionally get the Error 503: Backend Fetch Failed error when browsing the site, and almost always get it when installing a plugin or updating a blog post.

[image: Backend Fetch Failed]

I can rule out any plugins or gzip compression as being the cause of the problem as I had disabled all plugins and still saw this error, and reset the htaccess file to its original configuration and still get the error.

I've searched extensively and can't put my finger on what's causing this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you tried to open in a new incognito window?

Comment: When I refresh the page, the problem typically goes away. However, I need it corrected because users will likely leave upon encountering this problem.

Comment: 503 Errors are because of overload in Server. May be it be the reason.

Comment: Well yes, I know that there is an issue with the server connection. But, I need more specific information to be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: My host said this was a server side issue and not related to my site directly. Will wait and update if it is resolved. Many thanks.